# Connecting to Twitch using my C++ irc bot

Tags: c++, bots, irc, twitch

I have some problems connecting my bot to irc.twitch.tv. Connecting to irc.ubuntu.com is no problem tho..
When connecting to ubuntu I just send nick and then usr. With twitch I am sending pass, nick and then usr. 
I am really confused why this isn't working at all. Usually I think twitch should tell me anything but after my bot tells me that no special errors occur there is just no message at all. So I think the problem is within the connection not with me being unable to send a valid pass before usr and nick.
Because my code is a little longer I am posting it on pastebin I hope you can understand and analyse it:

http://pastebin.com/Win3CXbP

```
PS:  - My oauth PW should be correct it is not the string in the sample code.
     - I have the pw/usr/nick in the right order, nick/usr is wrong in code.
     - I want to say again, that I don't get any message from twitch or any errors.

PPS:  - I just tried using wireshark and when filtering for "irc" I got some data 
        with irc.ubuntu.com, but none with irc.twitch.tv. 
        Is the twitch adress wrong?
PPPS: - I am not completely into wireshark yet, but the only messages I am getting 
        on tcp port 6667 are 
                            "connection establish request"       
        and                 "connection establish acknowledge"
```

Comment: I think the sequence should be `pass, nick, user` whereas your bot seems to be sending `pass, user, nick`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer to this is pretty simple. I just found it out by just playing around with it.
It seems to be a problem in my little code, that I am not instantly sending my data to the server. So when I changed the "switch 3:" to "switch: 1" everything was working suddenly.

Still ty for all your help guys!

Answer (score 1):

According to the protocol document the client connection protocol order is:

> **PASS**
>
> **NICK**
>
> **USER**

Whereas your bot seems to be sending `pass`, `user`, `nick`.

> **3.1 Connection Registration**
>
> The commands described here are used to register a connection with
>   an    IRC server as a user as well as to correctly disconnect.
>
> A "PASS" command is not required for a client connection to be
>   registered, but it MUST precede the latter of the NICK/USER
>   combination (for a user connection) or the SERVICE command (for a
>   service connection). The RECOMMENDED order for a client to register
>   is as follows:
>
> ```
>                        1. Pass message
>        2. Nick message                 2. Service message
>        3. User message
> ```
>
> Upon success, the client will receive an RPL_WELCOME (for users) or
>   RPL_YOURESERVICE (for services) message indicating that the
>   connection is now registered and known the to the entire IRC network. 
>   The reply message MUST contain the full client identifier upon which
>   it was registered.

**EDIT:**

Also, even though the protocol suggests the `PASS` is optional, *some* servers expect a password even if one is not required to connect to the network. Sending a blank `PASS` is not enough. For those servers I send `PASS none`. (anything will do as long as the password is not empty).

Comment: I originally had it that way but changed around because it didn't work. So that's not it but still ty :/.

Comment: @ChrisDürr If you have another client that can connect to the network you can always use something like `wireshark` to packet-sniff the connection protocol.

Comment: Never used something like this but I might have a look at it when there is no answer until tomorrow.

Answer (score 1):

Twitch requires an OAuth token be used as the password. See here http://help.twitch.tv/customer/portal/articles/1302780-twitch-irc

Comment: But I am sending that, right? First Message I send is "PASS oauth:..."?! And shouldn't I get some error feedback from twitch then? Because as I said I get no answer from irc.twitch.tv whatsoever.

Comment: Are you using a real oauth token? Or are you literally sending 'some123numbers123'

Comment: Of course I am not sending some123number123 but I am not posting my oauth token online...